# Swift closures in autorelase pool accessing methods without self

Tags: ios, swift, nsautoreleasepool

This is sample code

```
func anyMethod() {
    // Nothing here       
}
var myVariable = ""

autoreleasepool { 
   anyMethod() // This should show error
   print(myVariable) // This should show error

}
```

it should show error

> Call to method 'anyMethod' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit

But I am able to call `anyMethod` without self, I wonder why this not showing error

[image]

Why this is working without  `self` ?

**EDIT**

Copy paste this class to re-produce

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AppGlobalManager:NSObject {
    var currentUserID:String?
    //Please ignore the method content as it is not the question
    func appendLog(string:String?) {
        print("LOG:",string)
    }


    func autoRelaseTest() {
        autoreleasepool {
            appendLog(string: "Any Log") // NO ERROR
        }
    }

    func normalFunctionTest () {
        normalFuncWithClosure {
            appendLog(string: "Test") //Call to method 'appendLog' in closure requires explicit 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
        }
    }

    func normalFuncWithClosure (completion:@escaping() -> Void) {

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
             completion()
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: Why should it show an error? `anyMethod()` and `myVariable` are not *instance methods/properties* of a class. There is no “self” in your code.

Comment: @MartinR Sir,  Yes it is If next to autoreleasepool If I add  `DispatchQueue.main.async {
                anyMethod()
            }` this shows error. this means it is instance method of class

Comment: @MartinR Sir added screenshot may helpful

Comment: I cannot see a class in your code, please post a [mcve]. – But the difference is most probably this: `DispatchQueue.main.async` takes an @escaping closure parameter, and `autoreleasepool` not.

Comment: @MartinR Sir. Done Could you please take a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling an instance method or referencing an instance property in a closure requires explicit `self` if that closure is passed to a function taking an `@escaping` parameter. That makes it explicit that the `self` is possibly captured beyond the duration of the function call.

If the function parameter is not `@escaping` then no explicit `self` is required.

Here is a self-contained example:

```
func funcTakingNonescapingClosure(_ closure: () -> Void) { }
func funcTakingEscapingClosure(_ closure: @escaping () -> Void) { }

class Foo {

    func anyMethod() { }
    var myVariable = ""

    func test() {
        funcTakingNonescapingClosure {
            anyMethod() // No error
            print(myVariable) // No error
        }

        funcTakingEscapingClosure {
            anyMethod()
            // Call to method 'anyMethod' in closure requires explicit 'self.'
            // to make capture semantics explicit
            print(myVariable)
            // Reference to property 'myVariable' in closure requires explicit
            // 'self.' to make capture semantics explicit
        }
    }
}
```

In your example, `Dispatch.main.async` takes an escaping closure, but `autorelease` not.