# Why is `self` is not required in first closure?

Tags: ios, swift, closures, retain-cycle

1) I cannot understand why is `self` not required in first closure. Usually you get a compile-time error that goes something like this: "add self to make capture semantics explicit". `myCollectionView` is an IBOutlet and `myItems` is a property, they are both strongly reference by `self`.

2) Is it correct to write `[unowned self]` in second closure? Am I right to assume that because `myCollectionView` is referenced strongly by `self`, using `self` in its method's completion closure would create a retain cycle is I don't write `[weak self]`/`[unowned self]`? The second closure DOES require referencing `self` explicitly unlike the first one.

```
guard let index = myItems.index(of: someItem) else { return }
myCollectionView.performBatchUpdates({
    myCollectionView.deleteItems(at: [IndexPath(item: index, section: 0)])
    myItems.remove(at: index)
}, completion: {[unowned self] _ in
    self.doSomething()
})
```

Comment: The method is synchronous and the closure parameter not escaping. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443959/swift-closures-in-autorelase-pool-accessing-methods-without-self

Comment: self only required if closure is `@escaping`. In `performBatchUpdates` method you don't need self for both closures since both are not `@escaping`

Comment: @RJE the `completion` closure does require `self`

Comment: yeah, you are right only first one is synchronous

Comment: @realvadim see my similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56443959/swift-closures-in-autorelase-pool-accessing-methods-without-self

Comment: The second closure  is  optional and therefore “implicitly escaping,” compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/39619298/1187415.